# Cognito isSignedIn latency issue after successful login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios, aws-ios

In an iOS application using AWS Cognito.

Inside the `didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?)` method, I'm having trouble with the `isSignedIn` property which is not immediately true after a successful login.

When I immediately check for:

```
userPool.currentUser?.isSignedIn // false
```

But if I delay the check:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
    print(userPool.currentUser?.isSignedIn) // true
})
```

1) Why is the `isSignedIn` property not immediately true ?

2) How to deal with this if I need to do a `getDetails()` in order to update the UI ? It is a problem since calling `getDetails()` with `isSignedIn` still false will cause the SDK to kick-start the authentication process again.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue and the way that I get passed was this:

Right after signing in, when you have the username and password, in the Cognito delegate method: didCompleteStepWithError, call this method:

```
- (AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession *> *)getSession:(NSString *)username
                                                password:(NSString *)password
                                          validationData:(nullable NSArray<AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType *> *)validationData;
```

Code will be something like this:

```
self.user.getSession(username, password:password).continueWithBlock(block: { (result) -> Any? in
       if let idToken = result.result?.idToken{
           //YOU HAVE THE TOKEN
           if self.user?.isSignedIn ?? false{
               print("user finally signed in")
           }
           else{
               print("something weird happened")
           }
       }
})
```

for me doing this got the user status correct.  Definitely not ideal but it did the job for me.